# How to extract, rename, and move files via scripting

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, automation

I am a beginner in Python, so this problem is really daunting. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 with Python 2.7

I have about 3,000 zip files (Winzip) which each contain four shapefiles describing different vector features. These shapefiles have the same four identical names inside each zip file. They are essentially a time series, with the same four data sets broken up to individual dates.

The name of the zip file contains a string somewhere in the middle of the name that I need to retrieve and include in the name of the extracted shapefiles.

Then I need to move each renamed shapefile to a different directory based on type.

For example:

```
 usdm_20001001.zip (I need the 20001001 from the title)
    |--DI_Callout.shp (needs to be renamed C20001001 and moved to a directory = Callout)
    |--DI_Type.shp (needs to be renamed T20001001 and moved to a directory = Type)
    |--file three
    |--file four
```

And so on, 3,000 times.

Comment: For example, one zipped folder contains 4 shapefiles with the exact name?  How do you differentiate them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Although you are using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop, this actually sounds like a pure Python question.  You are using *.zip and *.shp in your example, but they could just as easily be *.zip and *.txt.

Comment: Each zip file has the 4 shapefiles identically named. SO when I run my unzip all, (through the for loop, I end up with only the last extracted ones). Plus I really need to add the date to the file name or attribute table, since unfortunately there are no attributes in the shapefiles that link them to a time series (which is my ultimate goal).

Comment: That is correct. Sorry about that. This is a straight I/O question and file manipulation.

Comment: Well, it's here now. I do not doubt that this question belongs to Stack Overflow despite the existence of shapefiles so I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a [Zip interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html). I've put together a little script that has all the pieces you need but you will need to do some look-up or conversion with names and paths; there's not enough info in your question to decide on the names and I can't follow your folder structure.

```
import sys, os, zipfile

InFolder = sys.argv[1]

for Zfile in os.listdir(InFolder + "\*.zip"):
    # Open the archive
    Archive = zipfile.ZipFile(InFolder + "\\" + Zfile)
    # get the base name (no extension) and split it
    # to exract the ID.
    Zname, Zext = os.splitext(Zfile)
    Zsplit = Zname.split("_")
    BaseName = "C%s" % Zsplit[1]

    ZDir = InFolder + "\\" + BaseName

    # If the folder doesn't exist create it
    if not os.path.exists(ZDir):
        os.mkdir(ZDir)

    # setp through each file in the archive
    # extracting each one as you go.
    for member in Archive.infolist():
        InName, InExt = os.splitext(member.filename)
        # Not sure about naming here, you will need to do
        # some string manipulation
        OutFileName = "NotSure" + InExt

        # not sure about extract with a diffent name
        # so extract and rename
        Archive.extract(member,ZDir)
        os.rename(ZDir + "\\" + member.filename, ZDir + "\\" + OutFileName)
```

All the pieces are there: splitting strings, working with a zip file, testing & creating folders, renaming files and splitting file names from extensions. Use this as a basis and you should be well on your way.